# Building and deploying Dojo widgets

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, dojo, widget

I've written some basic widgets within a Java web app I've built using Maven. I've referred to the Dojo documentation here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/

to create them. What I want to do now is deploy them separately and access them from my original web app, but I haven't found a complete example on how to do this. Ultimately, I'd like to pass data to the widgets from my web app. This is my first attempt at widget programming, and I picked Dojo to create my first examples. It's also my first time using Dojo, as I normally use jQuery for any front-end work I do.

I'm using:

Java 1.6 and Spring 3.2 to build the web app

Maven 3.1.4

Dojo 1.9.2

Any pointers and/or links to tutorials much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy the Dojo widget code seperately as a web application/resource bundle. Then in your main web application you just have to define the path to the external web resource, I suggest reading following articles:

- [Advanced AMD Usage](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules_advanced/) (especially the part "Configuring the loader")
- [Configuring Dojo with `dojoConfig`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/) (especially the part "loader configuration")

You can configure your Dojo packages using:

```js
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        { name: "myWidgets", location: "/MyDojoResources/myWidgets" }
    ]
};
```

Then, if you use the following code in your web application:

```
require(["myWidgets/aWidget"], function(aWidget) {
    // Use "aWidget"
});
```

The Dojo AMD loader will then load the file from `/MyDojoResources/myWidgets/aWidget.js`. So if you deploy your widgets under the `/MyDojoResources` context, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, I suspected something valguely along those lines. I'll check out the links. I've used widgets (from Google, for example) that are accessed via a <scrpit> tag on the page, so I was wondering if something like that was possible using Dojo, to minimise configuration in the main app. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: No, that's completely against the purpose of AMD. AMD loads your modules asynchronously after the page is loaded (`<script>` tags don't do that) + the modules are scoped to the `require()` callback they're loaded at (`<script>` tag based modules don't do that either and usually use global scope).

Comment: I thought you might say that... What I'm aiming for is to deploy a widget on a server and then "drop" it in to any web app that cares to use it, without having to add dependencies to the client app, as in the Google model I mentioned. If I can't do this using Dojo, do you know how it can be done? As I said, I'm completely new to this, so forgive my naivity... :-)

Comment: With Dojo you always have to write your `require()` statement to load the modules that are necessary. However, you can minimize the JavaScript code in your main app by using declarative syntax.